# Python replace || operator with CONCAT function

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse a SQL statement as below.

```
SELECT '-' || IPC.ITEM, IPC.first_name||' '||ISA.last_name AS DEA FROM IpcDetails IPC JOIN IsaDetails ISA ON IPC.ItemId = ISA.ItemId
```

I have requirement to replace || operator with CONCAT function as below,

```
SELECT CONCAT('-',IPC.ITEM), CONCAT(IPC.first_name,' ',ISA.last_name) AS DEA FROM IpcDetails IPC JOIN IsaDetails ISA ON IPC.ItemId = ISA.ItemId
```

I thought of using Regex to split the expression around || and to replace the operator with function, Can someone help me in achieving the same?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: I don't know if a pure regex solution is going to be possible/very pretty - does the requirement specify you to only use regex or can you use other python functions as well?

Comment: I am open to use python functions as well. But using split and replace will require so many loops as the statement might have lot of inner queries and nested sub queries. I am afraid of the performance aspect. That,s why thought of using regex sub.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use some SQL parser for this. But you can try to solve this with regular expressions which are probably not the best tool for this type of problem.

Here is an example (check the comments to see what the code is doing):

```
import re

sql = "SELECT '-' || IPC.ITEM AS ITEM, IPC.first_name||' '||ISA.last_name, IPC.NAME, '0' || IPC.BAR AS DEA " \
      "FROM IpcDetails IPC JOIN IsaDetails ISA ON IPC.ItemId = ISA.ItemId;" \
      "SELECT '-' || IPC.ITEM, IPC.first_name||' '||ISA.last_name, IPC.NAME, '0' || IPC.BAR, IPC.FOO || '_BAR' || 'TEST' AS DEA " \
      "FROM IpcDetails IPC JOIN IsaDetails ISA ON IPC.ItemId = ISA.ItemId"

# Split all selects
selects = (re.findall(r'SELECT(.+?)FROM(.+?)(;|$)', sql, re.IGNORECASE))
for select in selects:
    origFields = select[0]
    fieldList = []
    # Split fields : not great to use split here as there might be commas inside of strings
    for field in origFields.split(","):
        # Split the field and the alias
        fieldAndAlias = re.search('(.+?)(\sAS.+|$)', field, re.IGNORECASE)
        if fieldAndAlias.group(1).find("||") > -1: # Check if we should do the transformation from || to CONCAT()
            concat = "CONCAT(%s)" % ",".join(fieldAndAlias.group(1).split("||"))
            concat += fieldAndAlias.group(2)
            fieldList.append(concat)
        else: # Field where no concat to be done
            fieldList.append(field)
    # Put everthing back again.
    newSQL = "SELECT %s FROM %s" % (",".join(fieldList), select[1])
    print(newSQL)
```

If you run this script you will see this printed out on the console:

```
SELECT CONCAT( '-' , IPC.ITEM) AS ITEM,CONCAT( IPC.first_name,' ',ISA.last_name), IPC.NAME,CONCAT( '0' , IPC.BAR) AS DEA  FROM  IpcDetails IPC JOIN IsaDetails ISA ON IPC.ItemId = ISA.ItemId
SELECT CONCAT( '-' , IPC.ITEM),CONCAT( IPC.first_name,' ',ISA.last_name), IPC.NAME,CONCAT( '0' , IPC.BAR),CONCAT( IPC.FOO , '_BAR' , 'TEST') AS DEA  FROM  IpcDetails IPC JOIN IsaDetails ISA ON IPC.ItemId = ISA.ItemId
```

This solution does not deal with sub selects and also aliases without the "AS" keyword. So yes: you need a proper SQL parser to do a really professional job. Regular expressions are not enough for this job.